# The project name '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]

Tags: npm, react-native, npm-start

I'm using mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl packpage in react native and I get the following error while running react native app through in command line.

A problem occurred configuring project ':@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'.

> The project name '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).

I have tried to remove @ and / symbol in the project name.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'.

  > The project name '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, just check that project name and include should not have duplicate entry.
then try this

correct the package name in the dependency.

Just remove the [/, \, <, >, ", ?, *, |] characters in the name

1. project-name/android/app/build.gradle

```js
dependencies {
     compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    // here is the change just remove /, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, | in the project parameter
    compile project(':mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl')
}
```

2. project-name/android/settings.gradle

```js
// Do the same as build.gradle by removing /, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, | characters but remember don't remove in the projectDir
include ':mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl'
project(':mapbox-react-native-mapbox-gl').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/android/rctmgl')
```